# How to avoid redirection to "enable-cookies" page during controller unit test?

Tags: controllers, cookie, ecomdev-phpunit, unit-tests

I'm doing a very simple controller test using `Ecomdev_PHPUnit`:

```
class Foo_BarWishlist_Test_Controller_IndexController 
    extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Controller
{

    /**
     * @test
     * @loadFixture ~Foo_BarWishlist/default
     */
    public function fromcartAction()
    {
        $this->dispatch('checkout/cart/add', array('product' => 10));
        $this->assertRequestDispatched();
        $body = self::getResponse()->getOutputBody();
        $this->assertResponseBodyContains('success-msg');
    }

  ...
```

This test fails because `$body` is empty. When checking `self::getResponse()` more closely, I see that a redirect to the `enable-cookies` CMS page was sent.

How can I take care of this? Do I have to set the check-cookie manually? Do I have to open another page before (I tried already a `$this->dispatch('/')` before the actual dispatch)? Or is there a general cookie issue during the controller tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a setting for it in the admin panel:

Web > (Browser Capabilities Detection) Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled

This setting can also be set during the tests using a config fixture.

Comment: I am just afraid, that the session is not properly initiated, so even if I disable this setting, something else might not work?

Comment: You can add the session id in the URL trough Web > Session Validation > Use SID on Frontend

Comment: @Alex did you find that there were any issues with disabling the Redirect? Did you need to add the SID to the URL like sander suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this stack overflow answer will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612349/cant-get-session-singleton-in-ecomdev-phpunit-test

The basic idea is to mock the session so then your "add to cart" action is successful instead of redirecting to the "cookies disabled" page.

```
$sessionMock = $this->getModelMockBuilder('admin/session')

    // This one removes `session_start` and other methods
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()

    // Enables original methods usage, because by default it overrides all methods
    ->setMethods(null)

    ->getMock();

$this->replaceByMock('singleton', 'admin/session', $sessionMock);
```